# How do you obscure text in a password field in an iPhone Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I have a password field in my application (UITextField). When user enters text in the field, I want it to display `*` instead of the text they entered.

I have tried using the `UIControlEventEditingDidEnd` of `UITextField` but it only shows one `*` at the end when editing but I want it to display the `*`s as soon as any text is entered, like in any online email password field. How can I get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 174):

I don't really understand your question, but I'm guessing you want a UITextField which displays dots for the characters, which every password field on the iPhone does. For this, you want to set the secureTextEntry property of that UITextField (UITextField has such a property because it conforms to the UITextInputTraits protocol) to YES:

```
textfield.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

Comment: Can I set other Characters instead of dots ?

Answer (score 154):

You can also set this in Interface Builder. Select your text field, and check the "secure" setting in the inspector.

[image: secure setting in Interface Builder]

Comment: Such a simple thing, yet not very obvious.

Comment: Thanks, I don't usually see ui builder instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a key path secureTextEntry of type Boolean and tick it in the User defined runtime attributes in the Identity Inspector.

[image]

Comment: You should prefer the "Secure" option under attributes to using runtime attributes like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of Xcode, (version 9), click on the UITextField that you want to set the input as password, then click on the attributes inspector and check "Secure Text Entry".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.3

```
textfield.isSecureTextEntry = true
```