# How to convert String into password(while entering the text)in UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

i am creating a Login Page.That Page Consists Of Three Fields(First One For EmailId,SecondOne For Password,Third One For HostName).I want to Convert The Entered Passsword
should Change Into Asterik Symbol.Can any one Help Me in Doing This..

Thanks And Regards
Girish

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you obscure text in a password field in an iPhone Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130953/how-do-you-obscure-text-in-a-password-field-in-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
textField.secureTextEntry=YES;
```

All the best.

Comment: @girish: Warrior is absolutely Correct. This is the right way to make text type as password. +1 for Warrior