# Hide password characters in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you obscure text in a password field in an iPhone Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130953/how-do-you-obscure-text-in-a-password-field-in-an-iphone-application)

How can I hide the characters a user is typing in a password field?

Comment: "How to mask letters in authentification[/password] text field" (I think)

Comment: please use english.. I have translated this by using google translator. If any mistake dont blame me...

Comment: I would imagine it's "Hello, please help me..." and not "Hello, thank you for helping me..."

Comment: @Evan, given that the translation was with Google Translate, I'm sure that's what she meant.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a `UITextField`, set the field's `secureTextEntry` property to YES. You can also set this in Interface Builder by ticking the field's "Secure" checkbox.